# Print weak component of a graph vector of vectors

Tags: c++

I'm programing a C++ program which has to work with graphs. And I have a litle problem with one of the methods. So, my structure looks like

```
struct graph {  
    std::vector <std::vector<int>> gr;
};
```

And I have a method which has to return vertices inside the weak component originating at vertex and it can only be called with existing vertex.

So here it is:

```
std::vector<int> weak_component(const graph& g, int vertex) {
    std::vector<int> ret;   
    if (vertex >= 0 && vertex < g.gr.size()) {
        for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; 
             i < g.gr[vertex].size(); i++) {
            for (std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < g.gr[i].size(); j++) {
                std::fill(ret.begin(), ret.begin(), g.gr[i][j]);
                std::cout << vertex; 
            }
        }   
    }
    return ret; 
}
```

I'm trying to fill another vector and return it. 
So for example: if I would fill a test graph with data

```
 0, 1
 1, 2
 1, 3
```

And call method `weak_component(g, 0)` the return value shoul be `0, 1, 2, 3`.
What am I doing wrong in my method? 
Thank you for help.

Comment: `std::fill(ret.begin(), ret.begin()`, maybe there is something wrong here.

Comment: @Holt why do you think so?

Comment: You should check the doc of [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/), you have `first = last` so you are going to fill an empty sequence, which is like doing nothing.

Comment: You probably want to use [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/), also `g.gr[i]` should probably be `g.gr[g.gr[vertex][i]]` but even with that your algorithm is not going to find components (it does not consider vertices that are not directly connected to your vertex).

Comment: @Holt than how should I change this?

Comment: You should use a *dedicated* algorithm. One simple (but not really good I think) would be to convert you directed to un undirected graph and then use a BFS or DFS to find the component. Another one (better) would be to use union-find structure (see, e.g., [this example in Java](https://github.com/nanwan03/lintcode/blob/master/Find%20the%20Weak%20Connected%20Component%20in%20the%20Directed%20Graph.java)).

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
    for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; 
         i < g.gr[vertex].size(); i++) {
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < g.gr[i].size(); j++) {
            std::fill(ret.begin(), ret.begin(), g.gr[i][j]);
            std::cout << vertex; 
        }
    }
```

to:

```
    for (int adj : g.gr[vertex]) {
        for (int elem : g.gr[adj]) {
            ret.push_back(elem);
            std::cout << vertex; 
        }
    }
```

don't use indexes unless you have to.  Iterate over ranges.

Your `fill` does nothing.  Replace it with a `push_back` to add stuff to the return value.

I'd also be tempted to add a `sort` and `unique`-`erase` to it to clean things up.